# CodeIgniter: CSS styles broken on IP address vs domain name

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have this working `base_url` setting in my

**Config.php:**

```
$protocol = is_https() ? "https://" : "http://";
$host = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : ""; 

if(is_cli())
{ 
    $config['base_url'] = '';
}
else if( stristr($host, "localhost") !== FALSE || (stristr($host, '192.168.') !== FALSE) || (stristr($host, '127.0.0') !== FALSE) )
{ // if local
    $config['base_url'] = $protocol.$host."/project2/";
}
else
{ // if server
    $allowed_hosts = ['website.com', 'www.website.com']; 
    $config['base_url'] = in_array($host, $allowed_hosts) ? $protocol.$host."/project2/" : "unknown-host.com";
}

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; // changing to AUTO didn't work too

// possible base_url results are http://www.website.com/project2 and http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx/project2
```

My project2/.htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

When I run the site at ***www.website.com/project2*** - everything is fine, but when I run at ***192.xxx.xxx.xxx/project2*** - css styles are broken

**My css** links are like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/stylesheets/somestyle.css" />
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: when you run at `192.xxx.xxx.xxx/project2`, where do the css link points to?

Comment: hi.. <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/stylesheets/somestyle.css" />

Comment: no, I mean at the browser page source

Comment: all of my css files are included inside the project.. when I try to view page source and click on the links, it does show the css.files and images inside the project folder

Comment: oh wait!! I seen this '403 Forbidden' on my bootstrap link.. but i searched the folder, it's in there..

Comment: did the bootstrap link have a different path than the rest css?

Comment: Can you show the actual print out `<link>` tags here (both the one that works and the one doesn't).

Comment: use syntax like this `<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/stylesheets/somestyle.css'; ?>`

Comment: it works well now guys. silly me, just needed a file permission to my css files. thank you for the hints guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me! **I just changed permissions (to grant all)** on my .css files and all worked well now!

My CSS links we're blocked by a file permission that's why my links are broken.

Thanks you guys for all the hints specially on the ***view-source*** part. Really helped me a lot!